# calling a get method from a url string with two parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to call an action method GET with two string parameters. from the following url.

http://local:64255/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=7da7d&code=vJIT0

```
// GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
  [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
        return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
    }
```

This result in 404 Resourse not found.
Any thoughts , what i am missing here .
Thanks.

Comment: What's the deal with this versus [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62610838/confirmemail-action-method-returns-404?rq=1) ?

Comment: The issue here is rather related with the subdomain in URL, this is why the method not being called, i am trying to fix that. thx

Comment: What subdomain?

Comment: http://CompanyA.local:64255/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=7da7d&code=vJIT0         is not hitting the method

Comment: But http://local:64255/... does? (Your question doesnt mention CompanyA)

Comment: You need to show how routing is configured at the app, controller and method level then maybe someone can spot which one isn't configured right. The code shown isn't relevant to the question. Are you using attribute routing? What's the controller called? ...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
```

To

```
ConfirmEmail([FromQuery]string userId, [FromQuery]string code)
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for responding to thread, I am using mvc5 not Core, [From Query]  requires to install an assembly, i am not sure if this is available in mvc.

Comment: I remember using FromQuery and FromBody at 2015. .net core was not there at that time.